# WPF OnRender not called on FrameworkElement

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I have the following custom framework element (which just draws a rectangle and some ellipses) with nested "visuals". Now I want to change some colors when the mouse enters or leaves the control. The code will be called but the color won't change even with InvalidVisual. Any idea what's wrong here:

```
public class Dummy : FrameworkElement
{
    #region Fields

    private Ellipse _bottomLeft = new Ellipse();
    private Ellipse _bottomRight = new Ellipse();
    private ContainerVisual _containerVisual = new ContainerVisual();

    private Rectangle _rect = new Rectangle();
    private Ellipse _topLeft = new Ellipse();
    private Ellipse _topRight = new Ellipse();

    #endregion Fields

    #region Constructors

    public Dummy()
    {
        Initialize();

        _containerVisual.Children.Add(_rect);
        _containerVisual.Children.Add(_topLeft);
        _containerVisual.Children.Add(_topRight);
        _containerVisual.Children.Add(_bottomLeft);
        _containerVisual.Children.Add(_bottomRight);
    }

    #endregion Constructors

    #region Properties

    protected override int VisualChildrenCount
    {
        get { return _containerVisual == null ? 0 : 1; }
    }

    #endregion Properties

    #region Methods

    private void Initialize()
    {
        // Rectangle
        _rect.Stroke = Brushes.Red;
        _rect.StrokeThickness = 1;
        _rect.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);
        // Ellipses
        _topLeft.StrokeThickness = 1;
        _topLeft.Stroke = Brushes.Red;
        _topLeft.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Orange);
        //----------------
        _topRight.StrokeThickness = 1;
        _topRight.Stroke = Brushes.Red;
        _topRight.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Orange);
        //----------------
        _bottomLeft.StrokeThickness = 1;
        _bottomLeft.Stroke = Brushes.Red;
        _bottomLeft.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Orange);
        //----------------
        _bottomRight.StrokeThickness = 1;
        _bottomRight.Stroke = Brushes.Red;
        _bottomRight.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Orange);
    }

    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
    {
        var diameter = 6;
        var radius = diameter / 2;
        var rectThicknessOffset = _rect.StrokeThickness / 2;

        var rect = new Rect(new Point(0, 0), finalSize);

        _rect.Arrange(rect);
        _topLeft.Arrange(new Rect(rect.TopLeft.X - radius + rectThicknessOffset,
            rect.TopLeft.Y - radius + rectThicknessOffset, diameter, diameter));
        _topRight.Arrange(new Rect(rect.TopRight.X - radius - rectThicknessOffset,
            rect.TopRight.Y - radius + rectThicknessOffset, diameter, diameter));
        _bottomRight.Arrange(new Rect(rect.BottomRight.X - radius - rectThicknessOffset,
            rect.BottomRight.Y - radius - rectThicknessOffset, diameter, diameter));
        _bottomLeft.Arrange(new Rect(rect.BottomLeft.X - radius + rectThicknessOffset,
            rect.BottomLeft.Y - radius - rectThicknessOffset, diameter, diameter));
        return base.ArrangeOverride(finalSize);
    }

    // Provide a required override for the GetVisualChild method.
    protected override Visual GetVisualChild(int index)
    {
        if (_containerVisual == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        }
        return _containerVisual;
    }

    protected override void OnMouseEnter(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseEnter(e);
        _rect.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
        InvalidateVisual();
        Debug.WriteLine("Mouse Enter");
    }

    protected override void OnMouseLeave(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseLeave(e);
        _rect.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
        InvalidateVisual();
        Debug.WriteLine("Mouse Leave");
    }

    protected override HitTestResult HitTestCore(PointHitTestParameters hitTestParameters)
    {
        return new PointHitTestResult(this, hitTestParameters.HitPoint);
    }

    #endregion Methods
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to replace the call to `InvalidateVisual` with calls to `Measure` and `Arrange`:

```
protected override void OnMouseLeave(MouseEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnMouseLeave(e);
    _rect.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
    Measure(Size.Empty);
    Arrange(new Rect(DesiredSize));
    Debug.WriteLine("Mouse Leave");
}
```

Comment: this works but now I am faced with new other problem :-) With a call to measure and arrange my rectangle will always jump to position (0,0)....

Comment: How is it positioned?

Comment: So what I do is, when a user drags a rectangle in my application I create a "dummy" element and position the element based on the mouse pointers:

                var p = e.GetPosition(this);
                _tempVisual = new Dummy();
                _tempVisual.Arrange(new Rect(p, new Size(100, 200)));

So is there another way to force a refresh without calling Measure and Arrange?

Comment: @FranzGsell: No, I don't think so.

Comment: Ok, thanks - then I have to double check how I can reorganize my current structure.